# delete an item in angular7

Tags: node.js, angular, http-delete

I want to delete a machine from the list of machines, in the backend, it's working fine. but when I try to delete it using Angular I get an error on the console :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown 
Error", url: "http://localhost:3001/machines/delete", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, 
total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: 
Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3001/machines/delete: 
0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:3001/machines/delete"
```

that's my file.html

```
 <button type="button"  (click)="delete(machine.id)"  (click)="showNotificationI('top','left',machine.id)" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>
```

my file.component.ts :

```
delete(id) {
this.machinesService.deleteMachine(id).subscribe();}
```

my file machines.service :

```
  deleteMachine(id): Observable<any>
```

{

```
    let myHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    myHeaders = myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWxpOmFsaQ==');
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/machines/delete`,id, { headers: myHeaders, withCredentials: true });}
```

and for the backend, I am workig with node js and my code is :

```
router.post('/delete', function (req, res) {
Machine.deletemachine(req.body, function (err, count) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json(req.body);
    }
});});
```

what am I missing.?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array named listMachines which contains all you machine objects, you could do something like this :

```
delete(id) {
    this.machinesService.deleteMachine(id).subscribe((res) => {
        let indexToFind = null;

        this.listMachines.forEach((machine, index) => {
            if(machine.id === id) {
                indexToFind = index;
                return;
            }
        });

        if(indexToFind) {
            this.listMachines.splice(indexToFind, 1);
        }
    })
}
```

Or even better

```
delete(id) {
    this.machinesService.deleteMachine(id).subscribe((res) => {
        this.listMachines = this.listMachines.filter((machine) => machine.id !== id);
    });
}
```

Deleting your object backend won't delete it on the front, you'll need to do it manually once the back have done his job

Comment: This line is wrong :     ``return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/machines/delete`,id, { headers: myHeaders, withCredentials: true });}``

Correct it like this :     ``return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/machines/delete/${id}`, {}, { headers: myHeaders, withCredentials: true });}``